# json wihin multiple loop issue on basis of id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I'm getting data from third-party API.

From the first loop, I'm getting all the bookings data. and within a loop, I want to get booking detail of each booking id.

But when I'm trying to create an array and trying to push into the JSON. it is looping for the length of booking detail and multiply with the main loop and getting whole data to the last JSON created.

But I need only booking id data for each id not whole data to the last booking id.

Can you please help me to resolve the issue.

Here is my script:

```
jQuery.each(bookings, function(index, val) {

  var bookingDetails = client.getBookingDetails(bookings[index].id);

  jQuery.each(bookingDetails.additional_fields, function(i, fields) {
    var id = fields.field_id;
    var value = fields.value;
    arr.push({
      id,
      value
    });
    xy = JSON.stringify(arr);
  });

  dataItems += '{"booking_id"' + ": " + bookings[index].id + "," + '"booking_service"' + ": " + '"' + bookings[index].event + '"' + "," + '"booking_area"' + ": " + '"' + bookings[index].unit + '"' + "," + '"booking_stid"' + ": " + '"' + bookings[index].code + '"' + "," + '"booking_scid"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_day"' + ": " + '"' + lesson_day + '"' + "," + '"booking_time"' + ": " + '"' + lesson_time + '"' + "," + '"booking_tname"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_tgname"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_bookdate"' + ": " + '"' + lesson_day + '"' + "," + '"booking_rpid"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_rpaddress"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_sub"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_pcode"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_wphone"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_mphone"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_mail"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_state"' + ": " + '"  "' + "," + '"booking_gender"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"booking_dob"' + ": " + '" "' + "," + '"additional_fields"' + ": " + xy + "},";
});

apidata = dataItems;
apidata = dataItems.substring(0, dataItems.length - 1);
apidata = "[" + apidata + "]";
});
```

Comment: can you share the json structure that you are dealing with?

Comment: JSON data is larger so here you can check: https://jsfiddle.net/nisha18/vzotdpxL/2/

Comment: which fields are you after? booking_id and b_id?

Comment: b_id is same as booking_id.

Comment: it's unclear what you are after, if you can explain a bit more about what you need after parsing the JSON, then people can help you more.

Comment: I have booking id's like 639, 651 and they having 12 additional fields array so I have created another loop to get their data. But for last booking id it is combining the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199549/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-nisha-sharma).

Comment: @NishaSharma what is expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor your code by using `forEach` to iterate the array and using `backticks` to create multi-line strings.

The bug here maybe with the usage of an index variable to fetch `additional_fields`. Please find below the refactored code.

```js
(function($) {
  var JSONRpcClientException = function(code, message) {
    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
  }

  JSONRpcClientException.prototype = jQuery.extend(JSONRpcClientException.prototype, {

    /**
     * Magic method. COnvert object to string.
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    toString: function() {
      return '[' + this.code + '] ' + this.message;
    }
  });

  /**
   * JSON-RPC Client
   * 
   * @param Object options
   */
  var JSONRpcClient = function(options) {
    this.setOptions(options);
    this.init();
  }
  JSONRpcClient.prototype = jQuery.extend(JSONRpcClient.prototype, {

    /**
     * Default options
     */
    options: {
      'onerror': function() {},
      'onsuccess': function() {},
      'url': '',
      'headers': {}
    },
    current: 1,
    onerror: null,
    onsuccess: null,
    onstart: null,

    /**
     * Init client
     */
    init: function() {
      this.onerror = this.getParam('onerror');
      this.onsuccess = this.getParam('onsuccess');

      this.initMethods();
    },

    /**
     * Init API methiods by url
     */
    initMethods: function() {
      var instance = this;
      // get all methods
      jQuery.ajax(this.getParam('url'), {
        'async': false,
        'success': function(data) {
          if (data.methods) {
            // create method
            jQuery.each(data.methods, function(methodName, methodParams) {
              var method = function() {
                var params = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                  params.push(arguments[i]);
                }
                var id = (instance.current++);
                var callback = params[params.length - 1];
                var request = {
                  jsonrpc: '2.0',
                  method: methodName,
                  params: params,
                  id: id
                };

                var async = false;
                if (jQuery.type(callback) == 'function') {
                  async = true;
                  params.pop();
                }

                var res = null;
                // API request
                jQuery.ajax(instance.getParam('url'), {
                  'contentType': 'application/json',
                  'type': methodParams.transport,
                  'processData': false,
                  'dataType': 'json',
                  'cache': false,
                  'data': JSON.stringify(request),
                  'headers': instance.getParam('headers'),
                  'async': async,
                  'success': function(result) {
                    if (jQuery.type(result.error) == 'object') {
                      res = new JSONRpcClientException(result.error.code, result.error.message);
                      instance.onerror(res);
                    } else {
                      res = result.result;
                      if (jQuery.type(callback) == 'function') {
                        callback(res);
                      }
                    }
                    instance.onsuccess(res, id, methodName);
                  }
                });
                if (!async) {
                  return res;
                }
              }

              instance[methodName] = method;
            });
          } else {
            throw Exception("Methods could not be found");
          }
        }
      });
    },

    /**
     * Set client options
     * 
     * @param Object options
     */
    setOptions: function(options) {
      this.options = jQuery.extend({}, this.options, options);
    },

    /**
     * Get client param, if param is not available in this.options return defaultValue
     * 
     * @param String key
     * @param mixed defaultValue
     * @return mixed
     */
    getParam: function(key, defaultValue) {
      if (jQuery.type(this.options[key]) != 'undefined') {
        return this.options[key];
      }
      return defaultValue;
    }

  });

  var loginClient = new JSONRpcClient({
    'url': 'https://user-api.simplybook.me' + '/login',
    'onerror': function(error) {},
  });
  var token = loginClient.getUserToken("skateclub", "admin", "TonyHawk");
  var company_login = "skateclub";

  client = new JSONRpcClient({
    'url': 'https://user-api.simplybook.me' + '/admin/',
    'headers': {
      'X-Company-Login': company_login,
      'X-User-Token': token
    },
    'onerror': function(error) {}
  });

  //var bookings = client.getBookings({"date_from":"2015-01-01"});
  //var bookings = client.getBookingsZapier(10);
  var bookings = client.getBookings({
    "date_from": "2019-09-10",
    "date_to": "2019-09-13"
  });

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var inc = 0,
      bx = 0;
    var dataItems = "";
    var bookItems = "";
    var bookData = "";
    var apidata = "";
    var newBookData = "";
    var arr = [];
    var xy = [];
    var z = "";

    bookings.forEach(bookingDetails => {
      additional_fields = client.getBookingDetails(bookingDetails.id).additional_fields;
      /* Lesson Date Time */
      var DayNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
      var start_date = new Date(bookings.start_date);
      var lesson_day = DayNames[start_date.getDay()];
      var cHour = start_date.getHours();
      var cMin = start_date.getMinutes();

      if (cMin < 10)
        cMin = "0" + cMin;

      var suffix = "AM";
      if (cHour >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        cHour = cHour - 12;
      }
      if (cHour == 0) {
        cHour = 12;
      }
      var lesson_time = cHour + ":" + cMin + " " + suffix;
      xy = [];
      additional_fields.forEach(item => {
        xy.push({
          b_id: bookingDetails.id,
          field_id: item.field_id,
          value: item.value
        });
      });
      dataItems += `'booking_id : ${bookingDetails.id}, additional_fields : ${JSON.stringify(xy)}`;
    });
    apidata = dataItems;
    apidata = dataItems.substring(0, dataItems.length - 1);
    apidata = "[" + apidata + "]";
    console.log(apidata);
  });


})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code to the answer, in the answer itself.

Comment: @JonP have edited, but this could have gone as a comment rather than a downvote.